# Scroll gallery to next page

Tags: android, gallery

Using a widget.Gallery to display a horizontally scrolling list of items. I've implemented paging in the gallery with what seems to be the standard technique: subclass Gallery and implement:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (velocityX>0) {
            onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, null);
        } else {
            onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);
        }
}
```

When tapping the gallery, I fade up next and previous image buttons. When clicking these, I want the gallery to animated to the next/previous page, respectively. I've tried calling onKeyDown from my next-button handler, but strangely this has no effect.
AbsSpinner has `setSelection(int position, boolean animate)` but animate is ignored in Gallery.

Comment: Are you making sure to call these methods on the UIThread?

Comment: Yes, they are called from a view onClick callback - on the main thread.

Comment: If I put a standard gallery in an activity and run this in the emulator, It also seems that the emulator left and right keys have no effect?

Comment: This is only a problem if the items in the gallery are so wide, that no other item is visible on the screen. Setting a smaller item width fixes the problem; but this should be working with full-width items as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what toucan said, but to elaborate further (comments limits are too short):

The problem seems to be the fact that the `Gallery` doesn't let the user scroll if no children exist in that position yet. `scrollToChild()` is the culprit when trying to inject the event:

```
private boolean scrollToChild(int childPosition) {
    View child = getChildAt(childPosition);

    if (child != null) {
        int distance = getCenterOfGallery() - getCenterOfView(child);
        mFlingRunnable.startUsingDistance(distance);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Interestingly, if you fling the gallery with your fingers, it will cause the child to be created. Then, if you let go of your finger (going back to the original position), and *then* press the button that activates the `onKeyDown` injection, *it will work flawlessly* - because the child is there.

Unfortunately there's no real solution since everything is private in that class. The only solution is to use `setSpacing(-1)` or something in the gallery, so left and right children are always created and visible, but just behind the currently selected view.

As a footnote, I'm really baffled as to why everything is private in that class (or in any other of the Android widget classes for that matter). This is one of those things that could easily be fixed with some small code change.

**Edit (Aug 2012):** For future reference, rather than trying to use a Gallery for this kind of pattern (when you want the user to swipe between different items while only one of them is visible), it's much better to use the Android's [compatibility package's `ViewPager` class](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html). In my opinion, the compatibility package is not as celebrated as it should be (it took me a while to get notice of it). For developers targeting Android 2.x+, it's a godsend.

Answer (score 2):

this is working

create 2 image buttons and gallery 
eg: 
nextbtn,backbtn  and gall

button code is avialable here

```
nextbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        gall.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);
    }
});

backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        gall.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, null);
    }
});
```

Comment: this only works if the gallery has items allocated on the left or right side. If the items in the gallery are full-screen (or more), no items are allocated by the gallery and the simulated key presses are ignored

Answer (score 0):

```
    String strMethod = velocityX > 0 ? "movePrevious" : "moveNext";
    try {
        Method method = Gallery.class.getDeclaredMethod(strMethod, null);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(this, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```